# I'm building Solar system, using three.js

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on assignment and not too good with `thee.js`, this assignment is on solar system,

1. problem I face,  is my images can't be rendered on Google chrome
   due to `CORS` policy but works on `firefox`. i have searched for answers
   but none worked.
2. I'm trying to generate particles in my assignment,  I was able
   create one single star but how to multiply the stars is problem. I
   used the `multiplyScalar` but it didn't work. this are some the
   articles, I read on particles, i was able generate a single but i
   need to duplicate on the whole canvas. here is Link of [aerotwist](https://aerotwist.com/tutorials/creating-particles-with-three-js/),[solutiondesign](https://solutiondesign.com/blog/-/blogs/webgl-and-three-js-particles)

## below is my code...

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> solar system project </title>
  <script src="three.min.js"></script>
    <style>
           body{
               background:#000;
              }
      </style>
  </head>

   <body>

   <script>

     var scene, camera, renderer, container;
     var W, H;

      W = parseInt(window.innerWidth);
      H = parseInt(window.innerHeight);

      container = document.createElement('div');
      document.body.appendChild(container);

      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, W/H, 1,1000000);
      camera.position.z=6300;
      scene = new THREE.Scene();


        //stars
         var  S_particles = new THREE.Geometry();
         var  S_material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({color:0xffffff, 
          size:20, 
          map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
          "img/snowflake.png"),
            blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
          transparent: true,
          sizeAttenuation:false,});`



        for( var i=0; i < 5000; i++){
               var x= Math.random * 2-1,
                   y= Math.random *2-1,
                   z= Math.random *2-1,

            particle = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z); 
            particle.multiplyScalar(6300);}



            particles.vertices.push(particle);


            var star= new THREE.Points(S_particles, S_material);

                scene.add(star);


         //sun 
           var sun, sun_geom, sun_matter;
           sun_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(830, 30,30);
           sun_matter = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
           sun = new THREE.Mesh(sun_geom, sun_matter);
           scene.add(sun);





           //earth
            var earth, earth_geom, earth_matter;
            earth_geom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 20,20);
            earth_matter = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
            earth= new THREE.Mesh(earth_geom, earth_matter);
             earth.position.x = 6300;
             scene.add(earth);



          renderer =new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
          renderer.setSize(W,H);
          container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

          animate();

          var t=0;
          var y=0;
         document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){

          y = parseInt(event.offsetY); });




   //this piece of used to animate
        function animate(){
             requestAnimationFrame(animate);

                sun.rotation.y+=0.005;


                  earth.position.x = Math.sin(t*0.1)*1500;
                   earth.position.z = Math.cos(t*0.1)*3500;
                 //camera.position.x = sun.position.x;
               //camera.position.z = sun.position.z;
                camera.position.y=y*5;
                 camera.lookAt(scene.position);
                 t+=Math.PI/180*2;

                  renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }

     </script>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle link so that i can see your running code and update at same time.

Comment: Do you actually know javascript? You should put the script in a separate file, so it's more manageable.

Comment: Also, you use Three.js here, which is based on WebGL, but they aren't the same thing. Believe me, if you had to work with pure WebGL, you'd be very screwed

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r72/three.min.js

Comment: here is the three.js fiddle are used. i know a little javascript

Comment: @ugo create a fiddle at jsfiddle.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1.) To get a texture without the CORS stuff can be done by creating a local server (try XAMPP, it's a good start for beginners), then instead of trying ti reach the images locally, try to get them trough the server.

2.)  To render multiple particles, you need to generate multiple positions for them, then you need to go through them and rebder a particle at every position.

multiplyScalar doesn't change the vector, you need to do

```
vector = vector.multiplyScalar(6300);
```

Comment: using XAMPP, am I going to create a Database for the images and query the images from the XAMPP

Comment: @ugo you need to create a webserver, where you store your site, nit a database.

Comment: @ Bálint , for the vector.multiplyScalar, should I create, something vector= new

Comment: @ugo You need to create an array of vectors, and create a particle at each

Comment: @gman Xampp is a simple server (at least compared to Apache). Running it is like 2 minutes

Comment: Xampp is far from a simple server. It's full apache + php + mysql. Apache has plugins and other things. It requires configuration files that must be changed anytime you want to serve a different folder. Otherwise it requires you to pull all your files in a specific place. All the other truly *simple* servers I linked to have zero configuration. You just run them in your current folder and they server the folder. Ctrl-C when done. There's no services that run on the background. No databases running. You can even run multiple instances in different folders for most of them.

Comment: @gman It looks like we define "simple" differently. For me, simple means pre-configured/works out of the box. Xampp does a great job of setting up pre-made config files. Without Xampp you need to 1.) Download appache and every extension (which is surprisingly hard) 2.) create config files 3.) run it. Xampp even allows you to turn different services off and on.

Comment: Xmapp makes Apache simple. But Apache isn't simple. It's much simpler to go `cd project1; devd` then later `cd project2; devd` and later `cd project3; devd` than it is to move your projects inside inside `xampp/htdocs` and then have to remove all those files when you want to work on a different project or start editing configuration files. All the *simple* servers *have no configuration*. Having to put your files in `xampp/htdocs` is just as bad as putting on your documents in `c:\windows`

Comment: i used wamp and everything works perfectly, thanks @Bálint